# mysql defaults to 3306 even if different port is defined in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, linux, port, my.cnf

**OS**: Linux

I'm trying to start mysql on port 1561 on the localhost using this command:

> /appl/mysql/5.6.14/bin/mysqld_safe
> --defaults-file=/appl/mysql/5.6.14/my.cnf --ledir=/appl/mysql/5.6.14/bin/ --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

I already have **port=1561** defined on my.cnf but somehow, the mysql service defaulted to 3306. Per checking on netstat command, mysql listens on port 3306 instead of 1561.

We managed to fix this by using below command, but I want to know the chances of the above scenario happening again and how we can avoid it.

command used to fix:

> ./mysql.server stop
> ./mysql.server start

Comment: Check which config file the mysql service is referencing.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The dba sister site of SO is there to help you with questions around opeating databases.

Comment: Even with --defaults-file, mysqld reads mysqld-auto.cnf and client programs read .mylogin.cnf.